# Using keypress to switch a bool

Tags: c++, winapi, keypress, boolean

I am writing a Windows C++ app which I would like to have detect a keypress (for this example, using the letter 'S'). When the key is pressed, the program should switch a bool value either on or off (depending on its current state).

I know that in console apps you can use `cin.get`, but I'm unfamiliar with the Win32 API. I also would like to be sure that when the key is pressed, the event is only registered once, i.e. if the user presses 'S' but holds the key down for a while, the program should detect only 'S'; not 'SSSSSSS'.

Comment: Please explain why you don't want autorepeat to work. Is it a game you are writing?

Comment: It's a scientific experiment I am writing. I am trying to toggle an event on or off. I don't want to accidentally have the event toggle both on and off at the same time, just once when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a windows message loop going, right? Capture [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check whether it's on autorepeat.

But I'd guess you are actually using a framework, be it MFC, QT or something else. The framework will wrap your windows message loop and allow you to capture key events, but if you want us to tell you how, you'll have to say what framework you're using.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but I have no idea what a framework is... How do I find out which I'm using? I've started with a working program and am editing it...

Comment: Consider:
1) Telling us what compiler/development environment you're using. I'd guess one of the Visual Studio versions, but which?
2) Learning about the basics. Take a look at the various results of different project types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6765tta0(v=vs.71).aspx) and compare with your example project.
3) Accepting answers to more than 35 % of your questions on SO.